# Excel VBA: "compile error: sub or function not defined" and the VBA selects "results ="

Tags: excel, vba

Public Function Myfunction(Roundnumber As Integer, teams As Integer) As Range

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Result() As Integer
ReDim Result(0 To (teams - 1))

```
For i = 0 To (teams - 1)
    For j = 0 To (teams - 1)
         If Not IsError(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j + 57, i + 3).Value) Then
            If Roundnumber = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j + 57, i + 3).Value Then
     Result(i) = "yeah"

            End If
         End If
    Next j
Next i

Myfunction = Result
```

End Function

Comment: There seems to be a typo on this line: `Myfuntion = Result`. Also, I think you need to declare the vector.

Comment: You need to **Dim** the variable *Result* before using it as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'I got it to work like this

Public Function Myfunction(Roundnumber As Range, teams As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Result() As Variant
ReDim Result(0 To teams, 0)

```
For i = 1 To teams
    For j = 1 To teams
         If Not IsError(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j + 56, i + 2).Value) Then
            If Roundnumber = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j + 56, i + 2).Value Then
     Result(j - 1, 0) = j & "vs" & i

            End If
         End If
    Next j
Next i

Myfunction = Result
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't declared `Result` anywhere with a `Dim`, when you write:

```
Result(i) = i + j
```

then VBA sees `Result` as a Sub or Function in which you pass the value of `i`. Since that Sub or Function doesn't exist in your code, then you get the error you're seeing.

You need to do something like this before your first `For` loop starts:

```
Dim Result() As Integer
ReDim Result(1 To Teams)
```

which will declare `Result` as being an array of integers and `ReDim` it to the size of `Teams`. You need to give it the right dimensions because otherwise VBA won't know how big it is and won't be able to store anything inside it.

Note that `ReDim` is an expensive operation so you do it only once when you know the size of the array.

Comment: Ok I don't get an error in VBA anymore but my formula is not working like I Hoped... when I use my function in a cell with input parameters as other cells I get a #Value! error... I tried ctrl + Shift + Enter with the correct number of cells

Comment: @Enmanuelgg: I'm not surprised. Your `Result` array is of type integer (because its content is created by adding `i` + `j` that are both integers), but your Function is returning a `Range`. Also, only the value of `i` has any effect on what goes inside the `Result` array, so the `For` loop for `j` is almost ignored. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to look in array with j rows and i columns for certain values equal to roundnumber which is a variable... then I want to save a value in a vector every time the program encounter such value, finally returning the vector... Its not finished yet but I have to get over the #value! error before I can figure out what result I want... its not going to  be i+j